# Value of $\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{1}k+\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{2}k+\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{3}k...}}}$

Tags: summation, nested-radicals

Note: I would like to add this is very similar to [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3474031/evaluating-q-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-dots) posted a couple months ago, which is the inspiration for this question, was proven to converge in one of the answers, and I believe a similar technique could be used to show that this infinitely nested radical converges as well.

My first intuition to solve this was to put this in terms of $n$ using
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
So then we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{1(1+1)}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{2(2+1)}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{3(3+1)}{2}..}}}$$
From here it should be simple to define a recursive relationship like this one
$$a_{n} = \sqrt{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+a_{n+1}}$$
Where $a_{1} = \sqrt{\frac{1(1+1)}{2}+a_{2}}$ and then it is clear that 
$$a_{n}^{2} - a_{n+1} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
I have no idea where to go from here.

---

Edit: as @mattapow pointed out in the comments, we can attempt to solve this using *Ramanujans's Infinite Radical Technique* but I believe this runs into some problems. As stated above there is a clear recursive relation:
$$a_{n}^2 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + a_{n+1}$$
*Ramanujans's Infinite Radical Technique* involves writing this in the form
$$F(x)^2 = p(x) + F(x+1)$$
and finding an 'ansatz', or essentially solving for $F(x)=ax+b$ in our case by equating coefficients. Here is my attempt, and inevitable failure:
$$F(x)^2 - F(x+1) = \frac{x(x+1)}{2}$$
$$(ax+b)^2 - a(x+1)-b = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x$$
$$a^2x^2+2abx+b^2-ax-a-b=\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x$$
$$a^2x^2+(2ab-a)x -a-b+b^2=\frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x$$
We can now equate coefficients to get a system of equations:
$$a^2=\frac{1}{2}; 2ab - a = \frac{1}{2}; -a-b+b^2 = 0$$
Which has no solutions. I cannot think of another approach.

Comment: The technique [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3080147/157116) may help, but I can't think of an ansatz that would work here.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Ramanujan's_infinite_radicals

Comment: [OEIS Wiki](https://oeis.org/A296041) lists it, but doesn't have an analytical solution. Where did you come across this problem?

Comment: @mattapow formulated by me, but apparently already asked according to your research. The Math Exchange link in the edit at the top of my question is the inspiration. My thought process is that the rising sum, which can be converted to its respective sequence of partial sums, would be easier to solve than the rising factorial.

Comment: Not much but by using Ramanujan-like radicals you can get; $$1=\sqrt{1+2\left(\frac{1\left(1+1\right)}{2}\right)-\sqrt{1+2\left(\frac{2\left(2+1\right)}{2}\right)-\sqrt{1+2\left(\frac{3\left(3+1\right)}{2}\right)-...}}}$$ And;$$3=\sqrt{1+2\left(1+\frac{1\left(1+1\right)}{2}\right)+\sqrt{1+2\left(2+\frac{2\left(2+1\right)}{2}\right)+\sqrt{1+2\left(3+\frac{3\left(3+1\right)}{2}\right)+...}}}$$

Comment: This is was achieved using the same method, as one can see in @mattapow's posted link.